# Convert from varchar to float SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have a column in `varchar` format and I would like to convert it to `float`. The values are like:

```
188234,62
188235
188235,43
188235,88
```

So, When I try to convert it I get an error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I thought that maybe some fields are not numeric and I checked with `isnumeric()` function, according to the query I concluded that all the values are numeric. Then I tried different queries to convert the field types:

**Query1:**

```
SELECT CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send.KM 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send.KM) = 1
THEN CAST(CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send.KM AS FLOAT) 
ELSE NULL 
END
FROM CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC(KM) WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(float, KM)) ELSE null END from CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send
```

However I always get the same error. Are there some other ways to convert `varchar` to `float`?

Comment: Isnumeric has well documented short comings, for example `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.')` will return 1, but `SELECT CAST('.' AS FLOAT)` will fail. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use `TRY_CONVERT`, otherwise you may need to use one of the many scalar functions posted online to extend `ISNUMERIC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a dot as decimal separator:

```
CAST(REPLACE(CarData.dbo.FinalData_OilLevel_new_send.KM,',','.') AS FLOAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186862.aspx)

The `,` present

try like this!

`select cast(replace(val,',','') as float) from table`

## [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35491)